# Backbone do not write URL to Browser History

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a modal that is popped when a user clicks on an item (for example a photo) The user clicks on a photo and I navigate from `host.com/u/1234/` to a URL `host.com/u/1234/postID` which is just a modal view in backbone

The issue is that when the user closes the modal (which would change the URL to `host.com/u/1234/`) and then clicks back in the browser, I want to user to go back to the previous page (let's say `host.com/feed`) but they are redirected back to `host.com/u/1234/` because technically in my history that is the last one written to history.

I am not quite sure how to to solve this issue. I have tried the following code which is per the Backbone documentation "To update the URL without creating an entry in the browser's history, set the replace option to true."

```
Backbone.history.navigate(this.model.get('user').url + '/' + this.model.id, {trigger: false, replace: true});
```

Comment: Our team have done this before, however we resorted to using http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/ rather than any built in backbone functionality, although that depends whether you currently use JQuery.

Comment: How are you navigating back and forth the model view..? Can you provide an [mcve]..?

Comment: I want to avoid 3rd party options if at all possible. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was that I needed to do the `replace:true` when navigating back to `host.com/u/1234/` from `host.com/u/1234/POSTID` and not when navigating to `host.com/u/1234/POSTID` from `host.com/u/1234/`

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, the [`navigate`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate) method you're referring to belongs to [`Router`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router), not [`History`](http://backbonejs.org/#History).

Try navigating using the router:

```
router.navigate(this.model.get('user').url + '/' + this.model.id,
 {trigger: false, replace: true});
// where router is the router instance
```